# How to upgrade Bugzilla on Windows

Tags: windows, bugzilla, upgrade

I installed Bugzilla with the handy Windows Installer (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32InstallPackages)
I'm trying to upgrade to 3.6.3 following [these instructions](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/upgrade.html).
I've downloaded the tarball and get to step 2.7.3.4 but my webserver starts throwing 500 errors when I try to access the site. The apache error.log says:
`The system cannot find the file specified.  : couldn't spawn child process: C:/Program Files/Bugzilla/bugzilla/index.cgi`

Is there something missing in those upgrade instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually upgrade, the #! line in all .cgi files needs to be updated to point to the perl path.

eg.  `#!"C:/Program Files/Bugzilla/perl/perl/bin/perl.exe" -wT`

The `SetPaths.cmd` script in http://landfill.bugzilla.org/win32installer/source/ will do this for you automatically when run from the Bugzilla installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

The handy Windows installer can also do upgrades--just install the 3.6.3 package over the version you have.

Comment: The 3.6.3 install package doesn't appear to be available (yet?).

Comment: oops; i've been focusing on getting the 4.0rc1 installer finished.  i'll build the 3.6.3 package today.